# On click top image, show modal and another image (behind modal)

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive

[image]

I'm working on a page where one can find an **image (RED BOX ON TOP)** - and behind it there is a **Bootstrap modal (YELLOW BOX)**.

**So, what I'm trying to do is:** when I click on the RED BOX, this(the red box) disappears and the YELLOW BOX is shown...but I need the **BLACK BOX(also an image)** to appear behind the YELLOW BOX.

I somehow achieved this with some jquery, but since the black box is going to be an image, **it must be responsive to small devices just like the top image(which is not the case). This is the part where I'm having some trouble and I would like your help :)**

```js
$(document).on('click', '#video', function() {
    $('#form_init').hide();
    $('.video').hide();
    $('#form_init').show().css({
        "background-image": "url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded)",
        "background-size": "contain",
        "margin": "0 auto",
        "z-index": "999",
        "width": "40vw",
        "height": "47vw",
        "position": "relative"
    })
});
```

```css
.video {
 background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded);
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 123vw;
 z-index: 9999;
 position: relative;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 451px) {
 .video {
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/oURrw.png) #1E1E1E;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: contain;
  width: 40vw;
  height: 47vw;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: relative;
 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form_init">
    <div class="video" id="video"></div>
    <!--IMAGE AT THE TOP-->
</div>

<div id="modal" class="modal in" role="dialog"></div>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP MODAL -->
```

**JSFIDDLE:**

[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/23hqmasy/)

Comment: So in the beginning only the red pic is shown, and after clicking it - it disappears and both the yellow and the black appear?

Comment: Exactly! The only thing here is that I need the image behind the modal to also be responsive, but i think my solution doesn't help that much :(

Comment: Hey, can you drop this into JSFiddle and provide a link? @Timmy

Comment: Okay, give me a moment

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/23hqmasy/ @lakshman_dev

Comment: modals usually have an overlay as full width background, which you can use as image, and the front image can be inside modal body or so

Comment: @sTx Can you provide a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile, I found a solution!

After `.show()` I added `.addClass()` and the class `.video-loading` :

```
$(document).on('click', '#video',function(){    
     $('#form_init').hide();
     $('.video').hide();
     $('#form_init').show().addClass('video-loading').css({
       "background-image": "url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded)",
       "background-repeat": "no-repeat",
       "background-size": "contain",
       "margin": "0 auto",
       "z-index": "999",
       "width": "100%",
       "height" : "75vh",
       "position" : "relative"})
});
```

Then, on CSS and inside the `@media screen and (min-width: 451px)`:

```
.video-loading {
    width: 40vw !important;
    height: 47vw !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: block !important;` in the media query that you wrote because, I see it overridden by `display: none;` by user agent styles

Comment: Thank you for your help @lakshman_dev, but the issue here is the image behind the modal. It's not responsive just like the top image and I would like them to be both equally responsive.

Comment: Try `display: block !important;` in the media query that you wrote for `min-width: 451px;` bcoz I see it overriden by `display: none;` by user agent styles. @Timmy